# Problem with BytesToRead in System.IO.Ports C#

Tags: c#

I want to Receive a string from Serial Port and Display with MessageBox in WinForm . But BytesToRead Property its not working fine and the string is corrupted . like receive half of it .
when i use for loop that condition is fixed value (i<20) , the string that is 20 char long will receive completely . but (i<BytesToRead) makes problem . here is the code :

```
string Data = "";

Thread.Sleep(1000);

for (int i = 0; i < com.BytesToRead; i++)
{ 
    Data += ((char)com.ReadByte()).ToString();
}
                
MessageBox.Show(Data);
///// End of Code

Example of Received Text : 12345678901234567890
Example of Displayed Text : 123456789
```

Comment: Every time you call ReadByte(), the BytesToRead property will be 1 less.  That makes a for-loop a very bad idea.  It would work if you delete `i++`, but consider `while (com.BytesToRead > 0) {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:

```
int count = com.BytesToRead;
int intReturnASCII = 0;
while (count > 0) {
intReturnASCII = com.ReadByte();
Data += Convert.ToChar (intReturnASCII);
count--;
}
```